# InnoSetup strip executable

Tags: command-line, executable, inno-setup, strip

How do I reduce the size of the executable file InnoSetup? I tried StripReloc, but I do not understand how it works, you can tell me how to use StripReloc command line? Thanks.

Comment: An aside: the "Why not use an EXE compressor?" part of the page looks fairly outdated with today's price of insanely cheap RAM. I can't even fill up the memory I have without running a VM, in which case saving a few megabytes from duplicate .exes won't save you. This especially for an installer which there will very likely only ever be one copy of which will run for a limited time and the install process will cause much worse "disk trashing" than the decompression.

Comment: Also, does putting "stripreloc /?" into a command prompt output anything? Or even just "stripreloc" without arguments?

Comment: I created a batch file into the program folder and inside the batch file I wrote: StripReloc setup.exe. I do not know what has to be added to /?, could you give me a list of commands? Thank you. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please open a command window in your program's folder, and at the command prompt type `striploc /?` and press `Enter`. What does the screen tell you?

Comment: usage:     stripreloc [switches] filename.exe

switches:  /B  don't create .bak backup files
           /C  write a valid checksum in the header (instead of zero)
           /F  force stripping DLLs instead of skipping them. do not use!

Comment: I tried to do: StripReloc /F setup.exe, but says he has already been stripped, but I've never stripped the executable in question. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to run stripreloc on an Inno setup, as it's [done already](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/readme.txt).

Comment: So how do I reduce the size of the program? It's too big, up to 1mb, do not understand why, I usually do the diskspanning, but the executable is 1 mb large, sometimes even more. I tried using UPX and ASPack, but nothing has changed, maybe 1kb. So how do I reduce the size? I have seen some installations and weighed 300kb executable. Maybe it's my problem? But I do not think. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Is 1MB REALLY that big? The size of the base Inno setup engine increased a few years ago as the scripting engine, then the wizard page engine was added but it's still insignificant compared to today's storage. If you really want to cut down the size, you can go back to older versions of Inno but then you lose  Vista/Win7 compatability, etc.

Comment: 1 mb is not so great, but it seemed strange that no one executable file, could weigh so much, with the NSIS executable is only slightly larger than 60-70kb, usually with programs in Delphi removes libraries that are not needed and becomes very light, but apparently we can not do this with Inno, oh well thanks anyway.

Comment: Inno's base setup (including uninstaller) is only ~700KB uncompressed, 300KB compressed anyway..

Comment: It won't make any difference, it's the same executable as the installer.